# How to find a vector field $v(x,y,z)$ such that the flux over any cone with vertex at origin is 0?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to find a vector field $v(x,y,z)$ such that the flux over any cone with vertex at origin is 0.

Comment: Take $v = \nabla \times A$ for any smooth vector field $A$ with finite support (or falls off to $0$ fast enough as $|x| \to \infty$).

Comment: @achillehui Could you please give some more details?